# Why gcc does not produce type mismatch warning for int and char?

Tags: c, gcc-warning

Why compiling the following code in gcc does not produce any type mismatch warning? `-1` is of type *int*, and `f()` expects type *char*:

```
void f(char c) {}
int main(void)
{
  f(-1);
  return 0;
}
```

Even if we explicitly specify the types, there is no warning:

```
void f(unsigned char c) {}
int main(void)
{
  f((signed int)-1);
  return 0;
}
```

What is curious: if we specify out-of-range value, the warning is printed:

```
void f(char c) {}
int main(void)
{
  f(65535);
  return 0;
}
```

`warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion`

gcc version 6.1.1

Comment: what happens if you make the function non-empty?

Comment: @talonmies `void f(...) { c = 'x'; }` - makes no difference

Comment: Well, look at the warning, "overflow in implicit constant conversion". Is there an overflow in your first example? If there isn't, why would compiler warn about something non-existent.

Comment: @hyde Because the types are different. Suppose that while testing stage I input values which may be converted, but in production user inputs something unexpected... This is the job of the compiler - to warn about  argument type mismatch. Anyway, in case 2) the values cannot be converted, but no warning is issued...

Comment: @hyde In case 2) I explicitly specify char as `unsigned`, so it can hold values from 0 to 255. Right? But then I convert -1 (integer type, 64-bit long on my machine) to the range of values 0..255. -1 is not in the range of 0..255. A warning must be given, because the types are different.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Misread code, deleting that comment. Testing when I get to compiler. But I suspect case 2 is just matter of insufficient warning enable ootions for compiler.

Comment: @hyde see UPDATE.

Comment: @hyde I posted a separate question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39720004/why-eof-coincides-with-valid-char-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a flaw in gcc's Wconversion warning option.

If enabled, this warning option warns for assignments:

```
int i = c; //where c is of type char
```

and passing variables to functions:

```
f(i); //where i is of type int
```

but does not warn for passing integer literals:

```
f(-1); //where -1 is of type int
```

According to the C standard the last example should also produce a warning.

Gcc is smart enough to recognize the integer literal fits into a char type, and doesn't warn, whereas if a value that doesn't fit is used, it does warn.

This is reasonable behavior, although a pedantic user would except a warning in the last example that should be silenced by a cast to type char.

Gcc actually includes a warning option to warn when a sign of an integer type is changed through implicit conversion. Use: -Wsign-conversion, and you will get a warning for the second example.

Comment: Where the bug should be reported?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko I'm confidant to say that gcc developers will not consider this a bug. It is reasonable behavior, i.e. more users would be inconvenienced by the change, than not.

Comment: How `-1` fits into `unsigned char` type (which ranges from 0 to 255)?

Comment: To your remark about "gcc being smart": does gcc reference mention this feature?

Comment: I tried to use `-Wall` in the beginning, but no warning was given. Isn't `-Wall` supposed to enable all warnings?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko No.

Comment: I get the warning only in the second case, but not in the first. Why?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Yes, you're right, there is no sign conversion in the first example.

Comment: The question remains: how `-1` fits into `unsigned char` type (which ranges from 0 to 255)? Also, I'm confused: in example 1) `-1` *is* signed. But you say that it is not...

Comment: @IgorLiferenko *-1 is signed. But you say that it is not...* Where did I say that?

Comment: By default `char` means `unsigned char`. And as you say that there is no sign conversion in the first example, this means that `-1` must be unsigned...

Comment: *how -1 fits into unsigned char type* By using implicit conversions. Assuming you read the other answer it should have been clear.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Type char is not unsigned by default. It can be signed or unsigned, and it is signed on your machine. Therefore no sign conversion.

Comment: Please give a link to any example which explains "implicit conversions". And in which standard it is stated that `char` is `signed` by default?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko I never said char is signed by default.

Comment: "... and it is signed on your machine". Where are the default values of "char" stated?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko *char*, *signed char* and *unsigned char* are actually 3 distinct types in C, where the signedness of just *char* is implementation defined.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko To get more warnings, use *-Wall -Wextra* for both *gcc* and *clang*. IMNSHO that is a reasonable default warning level for any new code, or code which you can fix to produce no warnings with these options.

Comment: @hyde If `char` is supposed to store character values, how can it possibly be signed by default? Do you know about any systems which make `char` signed by default and what difference it makes in handling characters and strings in comparison with systems where `char` is unsigned by default?

Comment: @hyde Is there a test program which will show if on my machine `char` is signed of unsigned by default?

Comment: @hyde Now I understand: `char` is signed by default on my machine, but in character and string handling functions it is treated as unsigned: `char a=-1; printf("%c %d\n",a,a);`

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Note that *printf* is not a very good example, because it is variable argument list function, so *char* will be converted to and passed as *int* anyway...

Comment: @IgorLiferenko as about signedness of *char*, just think of 8 bit character codes in HEX, and problem disappears (both -1 and 255 are 0xFF as 8 bit HEX number on any current CPU).

Comment: @hyde you say that `255` and `-1` are the same. But `EOF` is equal to `-1`. This is a contradiction, because the value of `EOF` must not coincide with any valid 8-bit character. I'm totally stymied now...

Comment: @IgorLiferenko 255 and -1 are same for *8 bit char codes*. Functions which return `EOF` to indicate error/EOF return `int`, and I think (would have to check to be 100% sure) C standard requires that `int` is wider than `char`.

Comment: @hyde I would ask if you two could please use chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/ Thanks.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko The update is a completely different question that must be asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask Please do not edit the current question to change it's meaning as this will break the Q&A format and make the answers irrelevant.

Comment: I asked the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39720004/why-eof-coincides-with-valid-char-value

Answer (score 5):

An `int` can be converted to a `char`. In `int` is allowed to be converted to a `char` in both C and C++.

From the C11 Standard:

> **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**
>
> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> 2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.
>
> 3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

From the C++11 Standard:

> **4.7 Integral conversions**
>
> 1 A prvalue of an integer type can be converted to a prvalue of another integer type. A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type.
>
> 2 If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source
>   integer ...
>
> 3 If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

If `char` is a signed type, it can easily hold the value -1. Hence, the behavior is predictable. The integral value of `c` in `f` will be -1. When `unsigned char` is used, the value of `c` will be an implementation-defined value but it is still allowed under both the standards.

Comment: Is C standard the same as C++ standard ?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko, it's not same but they follow these rules closely.

Comment: I specify explicitly `unsigned char`, but no warning is printed. Please explain how `unsigned char` can hold value `-1`.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko, when the argument type is `unsigned char`, the value of the argument will be implementation-defined but it is still allowed.

Comment: It is not clear to me in which part of section 6.3.1.3 of the C standard this is stated. BTW, a link to the quoted place of the original standard would be helpful.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko, it's paragraph 3. I have copied  the contents of the paragraph in my answer.

Comment: Paragraph 3 does not cover case 2) in original post, because the "new type" is **unsigned** `char c`. How can case 2) be explained?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko, you are right. I had left them out by mistake. They are in paragraph 2.

Comment: Do you know any good interpretation of the rules from section 6.3.1.3? It is not clear to me what they mean exactly.

Comment: @IgorLiferenkol, searching for "Integer conversions in C" turns up interesting results. I am not sure whether any of them has any in-depth coverage.