# Why EOF coincides with valid char value?

Tags: c, char, type-conversion

As said in comments to the answer to this question: [Why gcc does not produce type mismatch warning for int and char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39695149/why-gcc-does-not-produce-type-mismatch-warning-for-int-and-char)

> both -1 and 255 are 0xFF as 8 bit HEX number on any current CPU.

But EOF is equal to -1. This is a contradiction, because the value of EOF must not coincide with any valid 8-bit character. This example demonstrates it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  char c = 255;
  if (c == EOF) printf("oops\n");
  return 0;
}
```

On my machine it prints `oops`.

How this contradiction can be explained?

Comment: `EOF` isn't a character but a state. Comparing it to a `char` does not make sense.

Comment: hint: try `unsigned char`.

Comment: "*the value of EOF must not coincide with any valid 8-bit character.*" why not? Think twice.

Comment: `EOF` is an `int`, and all the functions that can return `EOF` return `int`, not `char`. Also, your program only prints `oops` if the implementation's `char` is signed.

Comment: `int` can represent 255 and -1 differently. There is no collision.

Comment: @alk because if we read characters from file, checking for EOF, then a valid character may indicate false end of file

Comment: @IgorLiferenko: ***All C's `char` reader functions which might indicate `EOF` do not return a `char` but an `int`***, to which the function's result should be assigned to (if you don't you loose info, by loosing certain bits). Then the result should be tested against `EOF`  and only if the latter test failed the result may be used as/assigned to a `char`-variable.

Comment: Have look at the bit pattern of a signed integer (with more bits then a `char`) that carries `-1`. You then will see where the end-of-file info is "hidden", is stored, is returned (and that it does not affect the possibility to still store 2^`char`-bit-width different character values in it's lower `char`-bit-width bits).

Comment: Enable warnings, including `-Wconversion` and make sure you use `unsigned char`.

Comment: @Olaf: Why the requirement for `unsigned`?

Comment: @alk: because `signed char` _can_ represent `-1` (but most likely not `255`). OP complained about not getting a diagnostic message. That should change it.

Comment: @Olaf: Ah, for the snippet shown! Yes, sure. I thought for something like `char c = getchar();`. For the latter a type conversion warning is expected for signed as well as for unsigned `char`s.

Comment: @alk: Is it just me or is today "what is this conversion?" day? I really wonder what teachers actually teach their students. Apparently not the fundamentals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compare an `int` value to a `char` value, the `char` value is [*promoted*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) to an `int` value. This promotion is automatic and part of the C language specification (see e.g. [this "Usual arithmetic conversions" reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions), especially point 4). Sure the compiler could give a warning about it, but why should it if it's a valid language construct?

There's also the problem with the signedness of `char` which is implementation defined. If `char` is unsigned, then your condition would be false.

Also if you read just about any reference for functions reading characters from files (for example [this one for `fgetc` and `getc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc)) you will see that they return an `int` and not a `char`, precisely for the reasons mentioned above.

Comment: If it's a valid construct, then it turns out that EOF belongs to valid character range, which it can't. Char and int *cannot have the same value*, even if it is the result of hidden promotion. If, for example, EOF was made to be 65535, the compiler would give a warning. For what reasons EOF is `-1`?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko *Why* can't an `int` and a `char` have the same value? Take the value `97` for example. No matter if it's stored in a `char`, a `short`, an `int` or even a `long long` it is stored as `97`, with the bits `01100001`. Multiple types, same value, stored exactly the same way. That the value `97` also happens to be the ASCII code for `'a'` doesn't matter, it's still stored as `97`.

Comment: Instead of "cannot" I wanted to say "must not". Anyway, if `EOF` was made `INT_MAX`, everything would be perfect. Obviously, it was a stupidity to make it `-1`.